# Pass argument to member function as with std::cout

Tags: c++

I want to create a class with a member function which can be used as std::cout. To demonstrate the problem I created this code example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass
{
public:
    void myFunc(? data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myClass myObject;
    int var = 1;
    myObject.myFunc() << "Text" << var;
}
```

As you can see I would like to pass arguments to the function as if I would have used `std::cout` directly. Is that possible? I searched the net and read a lot but didn't get it to work, can anybody help or link a page with more information?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `myObject.myFunc()` and have it passed those arguments. If you call it like `()` then it has no arguments.

To use iostream syntax like `x << y` then you need `myFunc()` to return something that has an overloaded `operator<<` so that `myFunc() << "Text"` will work. The obvious answer is to just return a reference to `std::cout` itself:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    std::ostream& myFunc()
    {
        return std::cout;
    }
};
```

But it could instead be a reference to a different object that derives from the `std::ostream` class, and so supports `operator<<` e.g. a reference to a `std::ofstream` would write to a file instead of to standard output:

```
class myClass
{
    std::ofstream m_outputFile{ "output.txt" };
public:
    std::ostream& myFunc()
    {
        return m_outputFile;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, if I use your first example, how could I manipulate the iostream within the class myClass before it gets printed?
The format of the the function call is, however, irrelevant to me, but I want to use the iostream syntax and need to manipulate the stream object withing the class.

Comment: @MartinHerrmann, I feel like Jonathan Wakely's second example about having an ostream member allows you to manipulate it.  For example if you needed to first output an iomanipulator, you can totally do that within myFunc.

Comment: @Wyck, I think I don't understand how the second example works exactly. Where can I maipulate the ofstream and how can I use it without saving it to a file?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate the stream object within the class"? That's a bit vague.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Let's say I want to access it to search for a keyword, copy it to a member variable, ...

Comment: That's a **much larger** question than simply enabling iostream-like syntax.

Comment: @MartinHerrmann You could potentially ask that larger question separately and then put a link to it here for context.  But all I meant is that the `myFunc()` body can say something like `m_outputFile << "xxx"; return m_outputFile`  Then you'd see how often you called myFunc, because each time you did, it would insert some "xxx" into the stream.  This might be a useful exercise for you to try. Especially since `myfunc() << 'a' << 'b' << 'c'` would then output 'xxxabc', which seems like it may be surprising to you.

Comment: I think I will do so as soon as I have time to ask the new question.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cout` "takes" inputs through the use of a binary operator: `operator<<` (also known as the streaming operator, or the left shift operator). It can be a method of a class, e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename T>
    A& operator<<(const T& x) {
        // do stuff with x
        return *this;
    }
}
```

or a free-standing binary function:

```
class A { ... };
template <typename T>
A& operator<<(A& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    // do stuff with A and rhs
    return lhs;
}
```

In your case, "streaming" data to a `myClass` can either be done:

- Straight up, not like in your question but like with `std::cout`:

  ```
  class myClass {
  public:
      template <typename T> void myFunc(const T& data) { ... }
  }

  template <typename T>
  myClass& operator<<(myClass& lhs, const T& rhs) {
      lhs.myFunc(rhs);
      return lhs;
  }
  ```
- Using a proxy object, which `myFunc()` returns:

  ```
  class myClass {
  public:
       struct StreamingProxy { A const & ref; }
       StreamingProxy myFunc() { return StreamingProxy{*this}; }
  }

  template <typename T>
  myClass::StreamingProxy operator<<(myClass::StreamingProxy lhs, const T& rhs) {
      lhs.ref.myFunc(data);
      return lhs;
  }
  ```

This code is a bit of a "sketch", but it does [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d34e1724a805fce5).

Comment: I tried to get your first straight up example to work, but I couldn't. There is always an `error: no matching function for call to`. (I also replaced `lhs.myFunc(data)` by `lhs.myFunc(rhs)`, since I think that was intended?

Comment: @MartinHerrmann: Yeah, typo... also, you need to make the methods public. With that fix, my code seems to work, see link in the edited version.

Comment: Your code helped, using `myObject << "Text" << var;` works. However do you think it is possible to extend the example to enable the use of `myObject.myFunc1 << "Text"` and `myObject.myFunc2 << "Tex"`? Would that be possible by changing the return value from a class reference to a function reference?
And why are all objects processed independently? Isn't it possible to take `"Text" << i` as one parameter?

Comment: @MartinHerrmann, no.  That's not how ostreams work.  Each time you write `ostream << item` it outputs the item and then returns the ostream again.  so `ostream << a << b` is like `(ostream << a) << b`, which is like first doing `ostream << a` then `ostream << b`.  Sending `a << b` into the ostream as a single entity doesn't make sense.  It's not concatenation of strings.  << isn't associative like + could potentially be.  It **doesn't** somehow compute `temp = a <<b` first and then do `ostream << temp`.  It's just a sequence of ostream `<<` expressions, evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @Wyck, I understand, but how is std::cout doing it then? Does it buffer the content and flush with std::endl?

Comment: That's sort of the beauty of streams.  Semantically, you just write byte-at-a-time.  A stream is just a sequence of bytes.  It's up to the underlying I/O to decide how to efficiently manage memory, buffer, flush and ultimately deliver output downstream.  _When it flushes_ is it an implementation detail you should try not to worry about.  But the short answer is that no, you don't have to output a std::endl to get output on cout.